# $W_p(\mu,\mu_{\epsilon})\to 0$ when $\mu_{\epsilon}$ is a mollified version of $\mu$.

Tags: measure-theory, optimal-transport

I would like to show that the [Wasserstein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) between a probability measure $\mu$ (in $\mathbb{R}^d$) and a mollified version of it $\mu_{\epsilon}:=\mu\ast\rho_\epsilon$ where $\mu\ast\rho_\epsilon(x):=\int \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y)d\mu(y)$ goes to 0, i.e. $$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}W_p(\mu,\mu_{\epsilon}).$$ I was told that to do this I can show that $$W_p(\mu,\mu_{\epsilon})\le\epsilon m_p(\rho)$$ where $m_p(\rho):=\left(\int d(x,x)^p\rho(x)dx\right)^{1/p}$ denotes the $p$-th moment. I think I have to come up with a particular transport plan between $\mu$ and $\nu$. I tried with the most obvious one to me, i.e. the product measure $\mu\times\mu_{\epsilon}$ but I didn't arrive to the desired conclusion.

**edit**

Using the plan $\mu\times\mu_{\epsilon}$ I get
\begin{align}
W_p^p(\mu,\mu_{\epsilon})&\le \int d(x,y) d\mu(x)d\mu_\epsilon(y)\\ &= \int d(x,y)\mu\ast\rho_{\epsilon}(y)d\mu(x) dy\\ &= \int d(x,y)\left(\int\rho_{\epsilon}(y-z)d\mu(z)\right)d\mu(x) dy
\end{align}
But now I a am stuck

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me. Can you provide some of the steps you did with this coupling?

Comment: @user159517, I added the steps I had in mind

Comment: $d(x,x) = 0$ if $d$ is a metric.  (Revisit your formula for $m_{p}(\rho)$.)  Also, you have not said whether $d$ is an arbitrary metric or some particular one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using the product measure $\mu \otimes \mu_{\epsilon}$ is it does not use the form of $\mu_{\epsilon}$ at all.  Convolutions have a very specific probabilistic interpretation, as do couplings, and the $p$-th moment you wrote also frequently appears in probabilistic computations.  Hence a second guess is to exploit this connection.

Recall that if $Y$ is a random vector with distribution $\mu$ and $X_{\epsilon}$ is a random variable with distribution $\rho_{\epsilon}(x) \, dx$, and if $Y$ and $X_{\epsilon}$ are independent, then $X_{\epsilon} + Y$ has distribution $\rho_{\epsilon} * \mu = \mu_{\epsilon}$.  Accordingly, if $\nu$ is the distribution of the pair $(X_{\epsilon} + Y,Y)$, then the first marginal $\pi_{1*} \nu$ equals $\mu_{\epsilon}$ and the second marginal $\pi_{2*}\nu$ equals $\mu$.  In particular, $\nu$ is a coupling of $\mu_{\epsilon}$ and $\mu$.

Also, I'm assuming that $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm.  However, all that is really necessary is that $d$ is translationally invariant (i.e. $d(x + z, y + z) = d(x,y)$ for all $x,y, z \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$).  In particular, other norms would also work.

With the coupling $\nu$ in hand, let's try to bound $W_{p}(\mu_{\epsilon},\mu)$.  I will use the random variables to do the computation since it is much clearer.  If that's not your style, it would be a good exercise to write down a purely analytic proof.  We find:
\begin{align*}
W_{p}(\mu_{\epsilon},\mu)^{p} &\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x - y\|^{p} \, \nu(dx \otimes dy) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\|(X_{\epsilon} +Y) - Y\|^{p}) \\
&= \mathbb{E}(\|X_{\epsilon}\|^{p}) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x\|^{p} \rho_{\epsilon}(x) \, dx \\
&= \epsilon^{p} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|\epsilon^{-1} x\|^{p} \rho(\epsilon^{-1}x) \, \frac{dx}{\epsilon^{d}} \\
&= \epsilon^{p} M_{p}(\rho),
\end{align*}
where the $p$th moment of $\rho$ is $M_{p}(\rho) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|y\|^{p} \rho(y) \, dy$.

It is worth noting (and can be used to simplify the computation above somewhat) that $X_{\epsilon}$ has the same distribution as $\epsilon X$, where $X$ has distribution $\rho(x) \, dx$.  In this sense, what we are doing in the last three lines above is simply computing $\mathbb{E}(\|\epsilon X\|^{p}) = \epsilon^{p} \mathbb{E}(\|X\|^{p})$ --- another indication that the probabilistic interpretation is very convenient here.

**Hint to "un-probability" the computation above:**  Let $\nu = \nu_{\epsilon}$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}$ given by its action on $f \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d})$ by
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x,y) \nu_{\epsilon}(dx \otimes dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(y' + x',y') \rho_{\epsilon}(x') \, dx' \right) \mu(dy').
\end{equation*}
Check that $\nu_{\epsilon}$ as defined is really a coupling of $\mu$ and $\mu_{\epsilon}$.  It is also worth verifying that $\nu_{\epsilon}$ can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} f(x,y) \nu_{\epsilon}(dx \otimes dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(y' + \epsilon x', y') \rho(x') \, dx' \right) \mu(dy').
\end{equation*}
Hence $\nu_{\epsilon}$ is looking very close to the diagonal.  Finally, check that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x-y\|^{p} \nu_{\epsilon}(dx \otimes dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x'\|^{p} \rho_{\epsilon}(x') \, dx'
\end{equation*}
and complete the argument as in the answer above.

**Edit:**  The product measure will not give a useful estimate.  To see this, consider the case when $\mu$ is Gaussian, that is, $\mu(dx) = (2 \pi)^{-d/2}\exp(-\|x\|^{2}/2) \, dx$ and let $\rho$ also be Gaussian:
\begin{equation*}
\rho(x) = (2 \pi)^{-d/2} \exp(-\|x\|^{2}/2).
\end{equation*}
One can then check that $\mu \otimes \mu_{\epsilon}$ is nothing other than two independent Gaussians, the second with variance $1 + \epsilon^{2}$:
\begin{equation*}
(\mu \otimes \mu_{\epsilon})(dx \otimes dy) = (2 \pi)^{-d} \epsilon^{-d} \exp \left(- \|x\|^{2}/2 - \|y\|^{2}/2(1+\epsilon^{2})\right) \, dx dy.
\end{equation*}
Now in the easy case when $p = 2$, writing $\|x - y\|^{2} = \|x\|^{2} + \|y\|^{2} - 2 \langle x,y \rangle$ and eliminating the cross term leads to
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d} \times \mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x - y\|^{2} (\mu \otimes \mu_{\epsilon})(dx \otimes dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|x\|^{2} \mu(dx) + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \|y\|^{2} \mu_{\epsilon}(dy) = 2 + \epsilon^{2}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar at all with the probability style but I think I understand the reasoning. I am just not sure how to go from the first line to the second line when using the "analytic style" (in the chain of inequality/equalities). Also I was unsure about something: when you say "$\nu$ is the distribution of the  $(X_{\epsilon}+Y,Y)$, this is the same as saying that $\nu=\mu_{\epsilon}\times\mu$ right?

Comment: No, the product measure ($\mu_{\epsilon} \times \mu$) doesn't work; that was what I was trying to say in the first sentence.  I added a hint to the answer that gives a purely analytic definition of $\nu$.

Comment: I looked again at the hint and I get the analytical version. This is maybe a detail but why is the action $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(y' + x',y') \rho_{\epsilon}(x') \, dx' \right) \mu(dy')$ and not $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} f(y' - x',y') \rho_{\epsilon}(x') \, dx' \right) \mu(dy')$ in the latter case we get get $\int \phi\circ\pi_1 (x,y)d\nu_{\epsilon}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \phi(y' - x') \rho_{\epsilon}(x') \, dx' \right) \mu(dy')=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\phi\ast\rho_{\epsilon}(y') \mu(dy')$?

Comment: ... but in the first case we wouldn't get the convolution right?

Comment: It depends on your definition of convolution of measures and whether or not you want to assume that $\rho$ is invariant under reflections.  If $\rho$ is not invariant under inversion (i.e. $\rho(x) = \rho(-x)$), then (at least with the definition of convolution I use) $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} (\phi * \rho_{\epsilon})(y') \, \mu(dy') \neq \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \phi(\xi) \, (\rho_{\epsilon} * \mu)(d\xi)$.  (Note that convolution is only a self-adjoint operation if $\rho$ is symmetric under reflections.)

Comment: Thank you. Last thing that is not so clear is the notation $(X_{\epsilon}+Y, Y)$. Is it the random vector with componants $X_{\epsilon}+Y$ and $Y$? What I don't get is that if this is the case, then its distribution $\nu$ is the product distribution, but as you explained, this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, $(X_{\epsilon} + Y, Y)$ is the random vector with components $X_{\epsilon} + Y$ and $Y$.  This is very far from implying that its distribution is the product measure.  What you are suggesting is the probabilistic equivalent of "Every coupling of $\mu$ and $\mu_{\epsilon}$ equals the product measure."  There are many choices of random variables $Y$ and $Y_{\epsilon}$ so that $Y$ has distribution $\mu$ and $Y_{\epsilon}$, distribution $\mu_{\epsilon}$, but nonetheless $(Y_{\epsilon},Y)$ does not have distribution $\mu_{\epsilon} \otimes \mu$.  In fact, these are "the same" as the couplings.

Comment: I think understand my error: if $\nu$ is the distribution of $(X,Y)$, $\alpha$ the distribution of $X$ and $\beta$ the distribution of $Y$, then $\nu(A\times B)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)\in A\times B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A, Y\in B)\not=\mathbb{P}(X\in A)\mathbb{P}(X\in B)=\alpha(A)\beta(B)$ and I just have the equality if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, is that it?

Comment: Yes.  All you can say is $\nu$ is a coupling of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Couplings and pairs of random variables like those are equivalent concepts.